# Move content added with pseudo-element:after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

thanks in advance for the help!
I created a menu with this code:

```
<div class="img-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">places</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">people</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">abstract</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">funny</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I then added a "/" sign after every menu item with:

```
.img-nav li:after {
    content: " / ";
}

.img-nav li:last-child:after {
    content: " ";
}
```

The problem is that if I add a margin to my items, the "/" is not centered like this:

```
ITEM1/  ITEM2/  ITEM3/  ITEM4
```

How can I reposition or move the "/" to be centered again?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add equal margin to your `:after` psuedo-selector to make it appear equal.

```
.img-nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.img-nav li:after {
    content: " / ";
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.img-nav li:last-child:after {
    content: " ";
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLsq104x/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding on the pseudo-element.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.img-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-nav li:after {
  content: " / ";
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-nav li:last-child:after {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="img-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">places</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">people</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">abstract</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">funny</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```